# Get kind array of sorted datetime array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, datetime

I have a long datetime array which has been sorted.

Is it possible to get another array, which consists of 0,1,2,3...., based on the datetime value?

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t = np.array(pd.to_datetime(['2021-02-01 00:00', '2021-02-01 00:00',
                             '2021-02-01 00:10',
                             '2021-02-01 00:20', '2021-02-01 00:20']))
```

I want to get the array below based on t:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
```

The first two elements are same, so `0` is assigned. Then, the next one is unique, `1` is assigned. The last two are same, `2` is assigned. Next values should be `3`, `4`, `5` ....

Comment: What is the logic in getting `0,0,1,2,2`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal The array begins from 0 and if DateTime values are the same, the same value is assigned. Next, the value is added by one. I add the statement in the description now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `categorical`:

```
In [1410]: y = pd.Series(t).astype('category').cat.codes.to_numpy()

In [1411]: y
Out[1411]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int8)
```

**OR:**

Use `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True` to directly convert `numpy array` to `integer codes`:

```
In [1421]: y = np.unique(t, return_inverse=True)[1]

In [1422]: y
Out[1422]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2])
```